# Elasticsearch - Even data distribution in Elasticsearch multiple data directories

Tags: elasticsearch

I configured multiple folders in my elasticsearch.yaml as -

path.data: /home/esdata/part1, /home/esdata/part2, /home/esdata/part3, /home/esdata/part4, /home/esdata/part5, /home/esdata/part6, /home/esdata/part7, /home/esdata/part8, /home/esdata/part9, /home/esdata/part10, /home/esdata/part11, /home/esdata/part12, /home/esdata/part13, /home/esdata/part14, /home/esdata/part15, /home/esdata/part16, /home/esdata/part17, /home/esdata/part18, /home/esdata/part19, /home/esdata/part20, /home/esdata/part21, /home/esdata/part22, /home/esdata/part23, /home/esdata/part24, /home/esdata/part25

After inserting huge amount of data (apparently around 7.4 GB), I checked my data directories to know the pattern. I got the following output

[image: Size of data direcotries]

I am using Elasticsearch-0.90.3. My Elasticsearch cluster has single node and my index has a single shard. Now it's clear from the screenshot that my data is unevenly distributed among directories. Is there any configuration option by which I can insure even data distribution among all the configured directories?